# Offset for audio file played with AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios6, audio-streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer for playing audio file on iphone.

What I want is, when I stop playing audio at certain time and again start playing it then audio should start from the point where I had stopped playing it.

Anyone know how to achieve this with AVPlayer?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676461/how-to-resume-avaudioplayer-after-interrupted-in-background

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play at same time without closing app then use this code

AVAudioPlayer *player;

[player pause];

and after that

[player play];

Answer (score 0):

to find out where you are in a track when play pauses

```
time = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.av_Player.currentTime);
[self.av_Player pause];
```

then to jump to that position again

```
newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, 6000);
toleranceVal = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, 6000);
[self.av_Player seekToTime:newTime toleranceBefore:toleranceVal toleranceAfter:toleranceVal];
[self.av_Player play];
```